# Java: should entity shared in readonly between threads be atomic

Tags: java, java-8, concurrency

I have one entity with which works 1 separeted thread, every 10 seconds.
How it looked before:

```
class Bet {
   private String id;
   private Integer startingValue; // 10 dollars
   private Integer currentValue;  // 10 -> 8-> 9 -> 11
}
```

This dto is just an example. Every 5 sec this separated thread gets it and could increment or decrement value of currentValue.

At the moment, i am storing this dto in ConcurentHashMap, would it be enoung of safe concurency?
I guess, that i should store startingValue and currentValue as a AtomicInteger. Is it right at all?

Because, in all examples of dtos in multithreading were dtos with final fields and which were initialazed in constuctor, without setters.

I would like to say that for 1 Bet could be only 1 thread which makes some changes. There possible other threads, but they read only.

Race condition is not possible as we have only 1 thead which make changes to the Bet.

Comment: We’d need to see how it’s used in order to say whether it’s threadsafe. Use of `ConcurrentHashMap` is probably not enough. If `startingValue` never changes after construction, it’s best to make it final (no need for `AtomicInteger` there). It sounds like a good idea to use `AtomicInteger` for `currentValue`. Please add more code to get a comprehensive answer.

Comment: A “DTO”, [data transfer object](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object), is intended to merely shuttle data, not change it.

Comment: @BasilBourque sorry, i wrote this queston in late night. It is a entity, not a dto )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the field from Integer to AtomicInteger.

Even if you use `ConcurrentHashMap` you'll see inconsistent results. try running the below code multiple times and see the result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Map<String, BetDto> concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    concurrentMap.put("1", new BetDto("1", 1, 1));
    concurrentMap.put("2", new BetDto("2", 1, 1));

    Runnable runnable1 = () -> {
        BetDto betDto = concurrentMap.get("1");

        for (int i= 0; i < 5_00_000;i++) {
           betDto.setStartingValue(betDto.getStartingValue() + 1);
        }
    };

    Runnable runnable2 = () -> {
        BetDto betDto = concurrentMap.get("1");

        for (int i= 0; i < 5_00_000;i++) {
           betDto.setStartingValue(betDto.getStartingValue() + 1);
        }
    };

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnable1);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnable2);
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    System.out.println(concurrentMap.get("1").getStartingValue().toString());
}
```

**Note:** Of course, you can fix the above code using `map.compute` to make `get and update` operations Atomic and make the variable volatile. But I wanted to demonstrate the thing that could go wrong if you use non-thread-safe APIs

Now if you change the field to AtomicInteger and run it. you'll see consistent results.

```
class BetDto {
    private String id;
    private AtomicInteger startingValue; // 10 dollars
    private Integer currentValue;  // 10 -> 8-> 9 -> 11

    public BetDto(String id, Integer startingValue, Integer currentValue) {
        this.id = id;
        this.startingValue = new AtomicInteger(startingValue);
        this.currentValue = currentValue;
    }
    
    public AtomicInteger getStartingValue() {
        return startingValue;
    }
}
```

Change `for` loop from the above snippet with the below code:

```
for (int i= 0; i < 5_00_000;i++) {
     betDto.getStartingValue().getAndAdd(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Basically,  i guess that race condition there is not possible, as there is only 1 thread for 1 Bet. If we will have 1 bet with 2 threads who update them - it would be incorrect logic. So, in this case: should i use thread safety (Atomic variables, etc) ?

Comment: @WickedGame If you are confident that 1 Bet is accessed by exactly 1 thread then you don't need Atomic variable,

Comment: In that case, you do still need to do something to ensure that writes to the variable are visible to the other threads if that matters (either atomic, volatile, or a lock).

Comment: @TimMoore good point Tim. yes volatile would be sufficient.